# I closed the terminal while updating and did not reboot because upgrading apt is in progress

Tags: boot, networking, command-line, apt, reboot

I closed the terminal while upgrading, and did not reboot the PC because upgrading with apt is in progress. The desktop doesn't show everything that it usually does. For example, the icons in the Dock are missing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyboard short <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new terminal, and run the `gnome-session-quit` command to logout. Then login to your Ubuntu desktop environment again as usual and continue the software upgrade by running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

If that doesn't work then you will have to reboot the computer with `sudo reboot` or manually poweroff by holding down the power button and then cold start the computer.